# Will "composer install" update vendor files after composer.lock file is modified?

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

Let's say that multiple people are working on the same project where vendor files are maintained with composer. Person **A** runs:

```
composer update
```

command to update dependencies to its latest versions and stores the changes into the `composer.lock` file.

**A** now pushes `composer.lock` file and person **B** pulls it from the repository.

Now **B** has the updated `composer.lock` file, but outdated vendor files.

What should **B** do to update vendor files to version stored in the new `composer.lock` file?

Will `composer install` check for versions of vendor files and compare them with versions stored inside `composer.lock` and update outdated files?

Or is it necessary to manually delete all vendor files before running `composer install`?

Comment: Just running `composer install` will work. If any of the installed packages does not match the expected version it will be updated or downgraded then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `composer install` on an application with an existing `vendor` directory will cause packages to be updated (packages installed, updated and removed) so the `vendor` directory matches what's declared on the lock file.

Personally, if I'm running `install` I'll delete `vendor` contents anyway.

But that's just to make sure I'm not missing anything, and no unexpected artefact as the autoloader files or anything like that is left behind.